# WTF_forms and Bootstrap-Flask render form

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, bootstrap-flask

I saw that while using WTF_Forms we can render a form in basic way as: [render form in basic way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYxX1.png)

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('login') }}"> 
  {{ form.csrf_token }}
  {{ form.email.label }} {{ form.email(size=30) }}
  {{ form.password.label }} {{ form.password(size=30) }} 
  <input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
```

I also saw that by using bootstrap-flask, we can render a form quickly as: [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waFpL.png)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% from 'bootstrap5/form.html' import render_form %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Login</h1>
        {{ render_form(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

But when using render_form(form), I cannot control size of the input to display (example in earlier code: `size=30`
Is there any way to control size with render_form() ?

I expect to control size while using render_form(form)

Answer (score 1):

To add some constraints to your form and then render your form by using bootstrap macro (render_form) you have to create a class of your form inside your python file.

[WTForms quick start](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/crash_course/)

1. First of all you have to import **form**, **fields** and something called **"validators"** from wtforms module

```py
from wtforms import form, StringField, validators
```

2. Once you have this you have to create a class which takes **form** as argument. This class should contain fields which you would like to add inside your form. For simplicity let's focus just on **StringField**

```py
class MyOwnForm(form):
    login = StringField("LOGIN")
```

3. From now on you can create an instance of this form class and pass it into <render_template> method inside Flask route. That first argument with value "LOGIN" is just a name/ label of your field.

But still the question is:

> "How can add some limits of my input?"

in other words...

> "How can I validate values provided by the user?"

Now the **validators** comes in handy.

[WTForms - Validators](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/crash_course/#validators)

Validators is an object which contains many helpfull methods that will make your life easier. From setting a length of characters inside your input to checking if the value is proper e-mail adress or a weblink etc...

Let's use previous class and add that functionality:

```py
class MyOwnForm(form):
    login = StringField("LOGIN", validators=[validators.length(max=30)])
```

**So simple pseudo code is:**

- Create your form by using class,
- Create your fields inside the class,
- Add to fields validators to check conditions
- Create an instance of class
- Pass that as argument in render_template method
- Receive that and render inside your template by using Boostrap macro (in this case render_form())
- [Read documentation for more](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/#)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same code (from 100 Days of Code: The Complete Python Pro Bootcamp course) and the same issue here, so hellooooo brother-learner

I found that you can pass parameters to the render_form() macros, for example form_type='horizontal' and horizontal_columns=('lg', 2, 2) so you can manipulate the size of controls by changing the grid layout.

Try this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% from 'bootstrap5/form.html' import render_form %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Login</h1>
        {{ render_form(form, form_type='horizontal', horizontal_columns=('lg', 2, 2)) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```